# How to setup Cognito to replace Secret Keys when interacting with S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, mobile-application

In development, we have successfully written an image to S3 bucket and then get the url back so we can store the url.

Now that we're moving into production, we need to not include the access and secret keys.

Everything is saying to use Cognito, but we don't want to authenticate users.  We just want images that are stored in the app to be backed up online and store the url.  Every user can dump images in the same bucket because they will never access the images, just download via url.

Does anyone know, is there an invisible way to establish this connection securely to only read and write from the app without forcing users to login?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout [CognitoIdentityService](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html). CognitoIdentity allows developers to get temporary credentials to call other AWS service. So, developers need not put access and secret keys within the application. They can simply use the credentials provided by Cognito.

With Cognito, developers can configure if they wish the users to be authenticated or not. With CognitoIdentity authentication is optional. If user not authenticated, user will be given a new identityId every time. For authenticated users, identityId remains same. But it can easily be used for either case to get temporary credentials.